# PhD Thesis defence

Tags: thesis, defense

What are the salient points to watch during a thesis defence?
How do you know if your thesis is up to scratch before the defence?

Answer (score 4):

Your PhD supervisor should not put you up for the viva unless you are ready - this is a discussion that you have with them.

If they feel you are ready and you feel nervous that is normal. But at that point this is the type of advice your supervisor is usually best placed to give.

In some disciplines it is the supervisor who then contacts possible external examiners and sets all in motion.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the motivation for your research, a number of other salient points that you must be sure to have addressed/ have answers to, includes the following.

- The relevance of the problems you have identified to your area of study.
- The clarity of your objective and the extent of its scope (is it fit for PhD?).
- What level of familiarity do you have about the state-of-the-art in
  the field.
- How does your problem fit into (enhance/add value to) existing body
  of literature and where are your contributions hinged.
- The technical rigour of your method and accuracy (benchmarking etc.)
- Reason(s) for choosing your method. Do you have strong justifications?
- The significance of your contribution to your research area.
- The technical ability to interpret your result and what value it adds to
  existing body of  knowledge.
- Your presentation and how you defend the above mentioned issues
- In some cases, (although secondary)...publications